# Trying to identify the spec/format for datafiles with these markers

Tags: database, reverse-engineering, legacy, data-collection, legacy-database

I'm working with some binary multichannel data logger files, and I'm finding the following plaintext markers all in the header of each file for a given logging session:

- `RDX`
- `PPX`
- `IIX`
- `MMX`
- `GGX`

I swear I've seen these before in a legacy database format, but for the life of me cannot place where.

- Having no luck on DDG or Google, just keep getting autogenerated "filetype" website results...
- Went down a rabbithole re Borland Reflex and Paradox based on some obscure link based on the `RDX` marker; they don't grok the format even when the extensions are changed for those systems.  (Admittedly was kinda fun standing up a Win2K VM to test though.)
- Github searches yield no results other than base64 encoded content and 3-gram tuples in language models.

Anyone have an idea?

Thanks!